# Printing the 3 largest elements in an array, and linking it with the names in another array

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to link two arrays together. I know there are better ways to do it but this is what I need to do for the assignment. I have two arrays. One with numbers, and one with names, and it is one to one. I need to output the 3 largest amounts with their corresponding names. I am having trouble with the name part of it. Here is a snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define COUNTRIES 10

void rankTopThreeByTotal (int totalMedals[COUNTRIES], char countryNames [COUNTRIES][100]) {
    int i, first, second, third;
    char firstName[30], secondName[30], thirdName[30];
    third = first = second = INT_MIN;

    for (i = 0; i < COUNTRIES; i++) {
        if (totalMedals[i] > first) {
            third = second;
            second = first;
            first = totalMedals[i];
            strcpy(firstName, countryNames[i]);         
        }
        else if (totalMedals[i] > second) {
            third = second;
            second = totalMedals[i];
            strcpy(secondName, countryNames[i]);
        }
        else if (totalMedals[i] > third)
            third = totalMedals[i];     
            strcpy(thirdName, countryNames[i]);
    }
        
    printf("%s: %d\n", firstName ,first);
    printf("%s: %d\n", secondName ,second);
    printf("%s: %d\n", thirdName ,third);
}

int main(void) {
    int totalMedals[COUNTRIES] = {13, 14, 18, 12, 7, 6, 2, 9, 5, 4};
    char countryNames [COUNTRIES][100] = {"Japan", "USA", "China", "ROC", "UK", "Australia", "Kosova","Italy","France", "Canada"};

    rankTopThreeByTotal(totalMedals, countryNames);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trying to work with "parallel" arrays is very troublesome. You should make things easier on yourself by using a struct to group related pieces of data together.

Comment: Find the indexes of the three largest elements in the medals array, and then use those indexes to print the names. So for example, the comparison becomes `if (totalMedals[i] > totalMedals[first])`

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and I think the problem is that you are changing the values of `first`, `second`, `third` every time you check `if (totalMedals[i] > first)` is true, but you aren't changing the values of `firstName`, `secondName`, `thirdName`. That's why you aren't able to link the two arrays together. You have to do the same operations on the string array as well.

The last else if statement was also missing its curly brackets so those had to be added too.

The fixed code would look something like this: (Commented on the changes)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define COUNTRIES 10

void rankTopThreeByTotal (int totalMedals[COUNTRIES], char countryNames [COUNTRIES][100]) {
    int i, first, second, third;
    char firstName[30], secondName[30], thirdName[30];
    third = first = second = INT_MIN;

    for (i = 0; i < COUNTRIES; i++) {
        if (totalMedals[i] > first) {
            third = second;
            second = first;
            first = totalMedals[i];
            /*
            added the lines:
            strcpy(thirdName, secondName);
            strrcpy(secondName, firstName);
            */
            strcpy(thirdName, secondName);
            strcpy(secondName, firstName);
            strcpy(firstName, countryNames[i]);
        }
        else if (totalMedals[i] > second) {
            third = second;
            second = totalMedals[i];
            /*
            added the line:
            strcpy(thirdName, secondName);
            */
            strcpy(thirdName, secondName);
            strcpy(secondName, countryNames[i]);
        }
        //added the curly brackets for the last else if statement.
        else if (totalMedals[i] > third){
            third = totalMedals[i];
            strcpy(thirdName, countryNames[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("%s: %d\n", firstName ,first);
    printf("%s: %d\n", secondName ,second);
    printf("%s: %d\n", thirdName ,third);
}

int main(void) {
    int totalMedals[COUNTRIES] = {13, 14, 18, 12, 7, 6, 2, 9, 5, 4};
    char countryNames [COUNTRIES][100] = {"Japan", "USA", "China", "ROC", "UK", "Australia", "Kosova","Italy","France", "Canada"};

    rankTopThreeByTotal(totalMedals, countryNames);

    return 0;
}
```

You could run it to check if it works or not.